# Regular Expression City Name

Tags: java, regex

I use this regex to check the field City:

```
"[a-zA-Z]+[[ '-]?[a-zA-Z]+]*"
```

but it works good also for name such as:

> Sant'''''Angelo
>
> Andria---------Barletta

I would like that the special characters " ","'" and "-" between the words must be one and only one. For example:

> Sant'Angelo-Dei Lombardi

it must be good, but not:

> Sant'''Angelo---Dei     Lombardi

Comment: Americans won't like you, your regexp doesn't accept `D.C.` :)

Comment: It's true. After a little change, now it likes also the americans :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use parentheses for the repetition:

```
[a-zA-Z]+(?:[ '-][a-zA-Z]+)*
```

What you tried (`[[ '-]?[a-zA-Z]+]`) means a character class, containing `[ '-]`, `?`, `[a-zA-Z]` and `+`, effectively being equivalent with `[a-zA-Z?+ '-]`. Subpatterns on the other had are delimited with `(` and `)`, and the `?:` makes it non-capturing which is a slight optimization.

Comment: What about the rare (but valid) cities which have numeric characters in their names?

Comment: @noogrub Well, add `0-9` to the two alphabetical character classes.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to validate city:

```
public static boolean validateCity( String city )
{
return city.matches( "([a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+\\s[a-zA-Z]+)" );
}
```